# How to identify hashing algorithm

Tags: hash, ip

I want to identify the hash algorithm used by an online service. What I have now is thousands of pairs of original string and result hash.

Some examples:

```
62.152.39.195 25d10817d8d2836925
62.152.39.200 c20147df170843824c
```

The result is 18 hexadecimal characters, as you can see. Is there any algorithm for such identification? Perhaps something that's related to machine learning?

Answer (score 2):

No, the best way is trying to try each hash function, encode as hex and find the result hash within that string.

From Wikipedia about additional properties for cryptographic hash functions: "Therefore, a cryptographic hash function should behave as much as possible like a random function while still being deterministic and efficiently computable."

That line also means that *any* good cryptographic hash function can easily be truncated to a smaller size without loosing *additional* security. The amount of security is still the number of output bits divided by two.

All of this is presuming that this is a cryptographic hash. If it is a normal hash, then it may be possible to find a match without brute forcing (but I would not bet on it). If it is a MAC instead of a hash then you would need access to the key.

I presume that you've already tried finding the documentation of course.

Comment: I`ve already tried all hash functions, there is no one that create the same hash(

Comment: There are a lot of secure and non-secure hash functions, are you sure you tried *everything*? Again, apologies if I've given a negative answer, but if this is a cryptographic hash, you may be out of luck. Note that 9 bytes is a strange number of bytes for a hash. Maybe it is 8 bytes and a 1 byte additional info or salt. 8 bytes is also a bit short for a hash, maybe it is a MAC (in which case you need the key). If you are very lucky it could be a non-crypto hash, but in that case it is a bit large.

Comment: Well, not every hash function of course, but most popular ones